# Spring captura e erros

Tags: spring

seguinte...

Estou usando o spring para um projeto particular e queria saber qual a melhor forma de capturar erros.

tenho minhas classes repository:

```
@Repository
public class PrimeiraClasseDaoImpl implements PrimeiraClasseDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void salvarObjeto(final ObjetoTeste objetoTeste) {
        em.persist(objetoTeste);    
    }

... outros métodos....

@Repository
public class SegundaClasseDaoImpl implements SegundaClasseDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void salvarObjeto(final ObjetoTeste objetoTeste) {
        em.persist(objetoTeste);    
    }

... outros métodos....
```

Tenho também a classe de serviço:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PrimeiraClasseServiceImpl implements PrimeiraClasseService {

    @Autowired
    private PrimeiraClasseDao primeiraClasseDao;

    @Autowired
    private SegundaClasseDao segundaClasseDao;

    public void salvarObjeto(PrimeiraClasse primeiraClasse) {

        segundaClasseDao.salvarObjeto(primeiraClasse.getSegundaClasse());
        primeiraClasseDao.salvarObjeto(primeiraClasse);
    }
```

Eu quero trocar o void desses métodos para retornar sucesso ou erro, pensei em criar um objeto e setar o erro ...

Porém queria saber como capturo os erros e setar nesse objeto.

Não sei se tem alguma outra forma para trabalhar, como vocês trabalham nessa situação?

Answer (score 2):

A maneira clássica é você soltar uma exception e deixar o ponto do código que invoca seus métodos da classe anotada com @Service, resolver o que fazer com ela. Se estiver trabalhando numa aplicação web, um jeito interessante é isolar os tratamentos numa classe anotada com @ControllerAdvice, que funciona como um interceptor(aspecto) focada em suas classes anotadas com @Controller. Qualquer exception não tratada diretamente no controller, pode ser direcionada para métodos específicos da classe anotada com @ControllerAdvice.